# What are the best practices and tools to do NLU testing?

Tags: chatbot, nlu, nlg

I am new to NLU and would like to seek help and guidance in knowing the best practices and tools for NLU testing. Any reference links, Git repos will be helpful.

Comment: Recommendation questions, as well as opinion-solicitation questions, are off-topic here.